# Abreviation for white spaces at the beginning and at the end

Tags: regex

Is there any way to abbreviate this?

```
/ 1111 | 2222 /
```

I mean, I want a regex that matches 1111 or 2222 when they have white spaces at the beginning and at the end.

I have tried this below but it is not working:

```
/ 1111|2222 /
```

Comment: `/ (?:1111|2222) /`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/ 1111|2222 /` pattern matches  `1111` or `2222` .

You want to use a grouping construct here:

```
/ (?:1111|2222) /
```

The `(?:1111|2222)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that allows matching alternative char/pattern sequences.

Or, with a capturing group (good for regex engines that do not support non-capturing groups, e.g. POSIX ERE, XML Schema regex engines):

```
/ (1111|2222) /
```